# An object is travelling in a straight line.

Tags: calculus

> An object is travelling in a straight line. Its distance, $s$ meters, from a fixed point at time $t$ seconds is given by the expression: $$s=t^6-t^2-6t.$$
>
> a) Find $\frac{ds}{dt}$ when $t = 3$ and interpret this result.
>
> b) Find $\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}$ when $t = 3$ and interpret this result.
>
> c) Find the time in seconds when the velocity is $2m/s$
>
> (d) Using the results from 5(c) find the distance travelled when the velocity is $2m/s$

My attempts:

A) $\tfrac{ds}{dt} = 6t^5-2t-6$
If $t=3\Rightarrow     6\times3^5-2\times3-6
         = 1446\, \rm ms^{-1}$

b) $\tfrac{d^2s}{dt^2} = 6t^5-2t-6$
If $t=3 \Rightarrow      30\times3^4-2
             = 2428\,\rm ms^{-2}$

C) Velocity at $2\Rightarrow   6\times2^5-2\times2-6
                 = 182\,\rm ms^{-1}$

d) I dont even know where to start, i feel like its $182\times2428 $.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? :)

Comment: please share your efforts towards the problem. It is about taking derivatives so share your actual difficulty.

Comment: Hi John, you seem to be new here. Adding Latex in your question will make it more readable. Take a look here for a quick guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/103816 . You would get a far more better response on your questions if you show your own effort.

Comment: (c) and (d) seem ambiguous to me. Does "velocity" refer to the straight-line velocity, or to the velocity with respect to the fixed point?

Comment: @John Have you read the rudimentary theory of _Calculus_? Are you directly solving problems for just passing an exam? $s=t^6-t^2-6t$ is given; what do you get if you differentiate both the sides?

Comment: Sorry guys, i am new to the site, i'm really trying to understand how to do everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
Velocity $v$ is the derivative of distance $s$, that is $v=\dfrac{ds}{dt}$. You may know the rules of [differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules) like distributive rule, chain rule etcs. I'm thinking about $c)$ part yet, hope would soon expand on it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{ds}{dt} = 6t^5 -2t -6$$

Put $t= 3$ into this you get 
$\dfrac{ds}{dt} = 6 (3^5) -2(5)-6$

Do the same for the second part , by first differentiating $\dfrac{ds}{dt}$ to get $\dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2}$ and then plugging in $t=3$.

For the third part they are asking you for the Time at which the velocity is 2 m/s, velocity is $\dfrac{ds}{dt}$ , so we know that $\dfrac{ds}{dt}$ must be $2$.

So 
\begin{align}6t^5 -2t -6 &= 2 \\
6t^5 -2t -8 &= 0 \end{align}

Solve this.

For the last part you put the time value you got for the previous part as that's the time at $2$.

Comment: Do you know how to solve $6t^5 -2t -8=0$? Hit and trial seems impractical.

Comment: I don't think that is solvable in elementary radicals. Given the nature of the question I think an approximation will be appropriate here

Comment: Newton's Method maybe?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function

Comment: I don't think this is the function he meant, just take a look at the first 2 question how simple and straight forward, and the last part of the question too, and look at his attempts , the c part they ask time at 2 ms-1, and he has gone saying velocity at 2? O.o and then the last part he has multiplied his velocity by his acceleration and comments saying that he feels O.o I think this is high school question where he has made a mistake in the question by making it a quintic function. But good one though :p now it makes me wonder how to solve a quintic equation thanks to a high school question.